# handling un-handled exception MVC4 C# knockout and ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am using knockout and using my custom function given below to make ajax call to controller. if any unhandlled exception occurs it returns entire page as response which results on reponse displaying entire html of page please suggest proper way of handling this

```
function asyncComputed(evaluator, owner) {
var result = ko.observable(), currentDeferred;
result.inProgress = ko.observable(false); // Track whether we're waiting for a result

ko.computed(function () {
    // Abort any in-flight evaluation to ensure we only notify with the latest value
    if (currentDeferred) { currentDeferred.reject(); }

    var evaluatorResult = evaluator.call(owner);
    // Cope with both asynchronous and synchronous values
    if (evaluatorResult && (typeof evaluatorResult.done == "function")) { // Async
        result.inProgress(true);

        currentDeferred = $.Deferred().done(function (data) {
            result.inProgress(false);
            if (data.hasOwnProperty("HasFailed") == true && data.ErrorCode == 1)//For Session Time Out 
            {
                $("#timeoutmessage")
                    .html('<div class="modal-backdrop">' +
                        '<div style="color:white;" class="middle">' +
                        '<div class="row-fluid"><div>Your session has timed out, please <a href="/">Login here </a>again.</div></div>' +
                        '</div>')
                    .show();

            }
            result(data);
        });
        evaluatorResult.done(currentDeferred.resolve);
    } else // Sync
        result(evaluatorResult);
});

return result;
}
```

and my calling function is

```
  self.currentRevenue = asyncComputed(function () {
    self.currentRevenueinProgress(true);
    var duration = self.duration();
    var location = self.location();
    return $.ajax({
        url: getCurrentTotalRevenue,
        type: "GET",
        data: { "durationType": duration, "storeId": location }
    }).done(function (result) {
        self.currentRevenueinProgress(false);
        if (result.hasOwnProperty("HasFailed") == true) {
            self.currentRevenueError(true);
        }else{alert('success');}
    });
```

i am using asycComputed function for making ajax calls if any of the ajax call thows exception  all of the ajax call fails and result html of the page in response.
 Can i use filters here Please suggest

Comment: Have you looked into the HandleErrorAttribute? See http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/handleerrorattribute-or-error-handling-in-mvc-4/

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom action filter on the server which catches the exceptions and changes them into JSON responses.

```
public class MyErrorHandlerAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new { success = false, error = filterContext.Exception.ToString() },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
}
```

Then you just have to add the custom attribute to your controller action.

Comment: thanks @elolos i did already but i want to display error message on that particular area how i will do that

Comment: You need to check for the success property (or use HasFailed instead of success) in the result object.